# How to connect two subnet with Windows Server?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

I have some work to do in a small office. This office has two separate Internet connections. 
One is a kind of DSL line and connected through the Internet sharing router (DHCP). One is a leased line with public IP adresses (No DHCP). This leased line provide only 30 IP addresses and the gateway is provided by the ISP.

Some workers use private IP provided by the router, some workers use manually setup public IP.

There is a Windows 2008 R2 server with two NICs, connected to each lines. I want to connect/merge(?)/bridge(?) two subnet with this server so that users from the different subnet can access each other.

How can I accomplish this?

Something like, add gateway function to this server and public IP users change the gateway to point this server.. It it possible ?

Sorry for my rambling. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IF this server has interfaces on both network you can route this at the dafult gateway of each subnet:

GW-A: route add dest network -> Win2008R2 server / GW-B: route add dest network -> Win2008R2 server

And enable ip routing at the server: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545655

Hope it helps.